# Can't find existing element with Selenium when searching for n-th hit

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

I have mutliple Elements in my DOM tree with the following structure:

```html
<span test-id="list"  id="rLGMqz">bla</span>
```

Because the id is generated by the framework i define some test-ids i search for in selenium. The xpath-code to find those elements is as follows:

```
//*[@test-id='list']
```

This works but selenium.getText(path) only returns the content of the very first span element. I now want to try something like this:

```
(//*[@test-id='list'])[2]
```

to find the second element but selenium throws an exception (Element not found). Even if i just put the original searchterm in parantheses (like this: (//*[@test-id='list'])  ) the exception is thrown. I evaluated the expression with the firebug $x() method and everything seems to work there, but as soon as I try the same expression in java with selenium, it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a working solution.

Selenium expects a "/" at the beginning of your xpath expression. If there is no such thing (as in my case there is a '(' ) you have to prefix the xpath with'"xpath='.

In my case thats:

```
selenium.getText("xpath=(//*[@test-id='list'])[2]")
```

Answer (score 0):

`selenium.getText("//span[@test-id='list'][2]");` will be perfect ;-)

Comment: ''' - Invalid Character Constant. or did you mean " '''...''' "? I tried this in firebug, but it didnt work there.

Comment: sorry, the `'''` came from the groovy script I used for testing...
`selenium.getText("//span[@test-id='list'][2]");` should be fine